# php script stops after 360 seconds and shows 500 server error for large files

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on csv file upload. It is working fine for 3MB file. But when i am trying to upload 8MB file.It stops the script after 360 sec and shows 500 Internal server error. I had  changed max_execution_time and memory_limit and all other paramaters also.But not importing the complete data into database. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you checked the max file upload size for your server?

Comment: Can you specify what those "all other parameters" are? Also, have you checked for any errors in the log?

Comment: You tagged 'mysql' so I'm assuming you're importing something in a MySQL database. In that case you should take a look at LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: what about `display_errors = On` ? it will show you the error.

Comment: Did any Solution worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

look at `"post_max_size"` and `"upload_max_size"` in your .ini file. You'll also likely need to extend the execution time of the script, via `"max_input_time"` and `"max_execution_time"`.

## php way

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

## .htaccess way

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

[Read more](http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/)

Comment: In my php.ini file  Values are Set Like: ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1000M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '1000M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 1200);  
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

Comment: may be you are overriding them in a another place

Comment: set up display_errors = On or check your logs for error you have occured

Answer (score -1):

try to set max_execution_time code inside loop

```
ini_set ( 'max_execution_time', WHATEVER_TIMING);
```

and set WHATEVER_TIMING as you want

I means Try this

```
 foreach($records as $record ){
       set_time_limit(250);
       // Other Execution code
 }
```

set_time_limit(250); every-time your loop will execute record

Might fix your timeout issues.

Comment: Change an ini-setting in a loop??

Comment: max_execution_time  is set 900.

Comment: I had tried this but it is showing same error. I had tried this in my foreach loop.

Comment: Flagged for removal. This has absolutely no effect in any case. @Sherlock is correct, changing an ini setting in a loop? Why would you do that?