# 500 server error after 1 minute

Tags: php, mysql, timeout

I have a php script that takes mysql tables from a remote host and inserts them into the local database.

I need the script to run for an unlimited amount of time, but it keeps giving a 500 server error after exactly 60 seconds.

I have tried changing the ini vars like so:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('max_input_time', -1);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 15);
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 15);
set_time_limit(0);
```

And also setting them in the php.ini. When printing the configuration variables, I can see that these changes take effect. But my script keeps giving a 500 after exactly 60 seconds of execution.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I don't believe this can have anything to do with any size limits as suggested in the linked "duplicate" question. This is because when running this script, I have wildly different results on the database, sometimes inserting 100.000 rows, and sometimes inserting 300.000, and every time, the error shows at almost exactly 60 seconds.

I removed the database script and only ran a sleep(70) to see what happened with the time limits set as above, and the script still gives a 500 error after 60 seconds.

**UPDATE**

This is strange if I point the browser to the script and run it, it stops after 60 seconds. But if I close the browser before getting the error, the script will keep running on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php script stops after 360 seconds and shows 500 server error for large files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601330/php-script-stops-after-360-seconds-and-shows-500-server-error-for-large-files)

Comment: Are you changing the configuration on the remote server or the local host? Because from what it appears you are trying to do, you need to change the settings on both. However, you might want to adjust your script to not attempt to run for more than 60 seconds.

Comment: If you do `sleep(50)` before running the code would you still get an error after 60 seconds or would you get one after 110 seconds?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The options I am setting are being set locally and globally (in the php.ini). The problem is on this server, not the remote, I can run the script from my local without problems. I am connecting to a VPS from another VPS.

Comment: I did sleep(30), but the 500 still came after 60 seconds. The time was not added. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I hope this helps someone else who gets this same nightmare of a problem.

The problem occurs when you are running a script for a long time, but there is no output. I fixed it simply by making sure that the script output something every few seconds. For me it was:

```
$counter = 0;
while($continue === TRUE){  //The long loop  
    if($counter%1000==0) echo '.'; //write out a dot every 1000 iterations
    $counter ++;
    //Code...
}
```

I got a hint to my problem here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/277386/apache-2-2-cgi-timeout-configuration

This is something about how timeouts are inferred by apache if there is no output from the script for a number of seconds (60 for me).

You can probably fix this in some configuration file so you don't have to do the above hack.